# Android studio, ArrayList not displaying items in list view correctly

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have a spinner that i select data from which goes into a arraylist that is used with a list view to display the contents. I know the values are going into the Arraylist but when it comes to the list view it does not work correctly.

What happens is the first item will load in fine, but when i add another item the previous one disappears, while the new one is displayed one position down from the previous one, this repeats for each one i added.

create itinerary code:

```
public class CreateItinerary extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

TextView txtDate;

private Spinner spinnerAttraction;
private Spinner spinnerTransport;
private boolean saved;
// array list for spinner adapter
private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

private ArrayList<ItineraryAdapter>Entities;
private ArrayList<ItineraryAdapter>finalEntities;

private LayoutInflater myInflator;
private View myView;

private DBManager db;
private myAdapter adapter;

private int ID;
private String NAME;
private String LOCATION;
private String TIME;

static  final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
int hour_x;
int min_x;
private ListView ls;
private TextView TextTime;
private String ItineraryName;
private String URL_ATTRACTIONS = "http://10.0.2.2/TravelApp/get_all_spinner.php";
private String URL_TRANSPORT = "http://10.0.2.2/TravelApp/get_all_transport_minor.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_itinerary);
    txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectDate);

    saved = false;

    ls = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listCreateItinerary);

    myInflator = getLayoutInflater();
    myView = myInflator.inflate(R.layout.list_create_itinerary, null);
    spinnerAttraction = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAttraction);
    spinnerTransport = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTransport);

    db = new DBManager(this);

    categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    Entities = new ArrayList<ItineraryAdapter>();
    finalEntities = new ArrayList<ItineraryAdapter>();
    // spinner item select listener
    spinnerAttraction.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerTransport.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    new GetAttractions().execute();

    showTimePickerDialog();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    ItineraryName = bundle.getString("Itinerary Name");

    (this).registerForContextMenu(ls);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if(v.getId()== R.id.listCreateItinerary){
        this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuDelete:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_button, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (saved == false) {
        if (id == R.id.go_home) {
            final TextView alertMessage = new TextView(this);
            alertMessage.setText(" All changes will be lost are you sure you want to return back to the home page? ");
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Unsaved changes")
                    .setView(alertMessage)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QavelNav.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
    else if(saved == true){
        if (id == R.id.go_home) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QavelNav.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void pickDate(View v) {
    DatePickerClass datepicker = new DatePickerClass();
    datepicker.setText(v);
    datepicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
    System.out.println(getDate());
}

public String getDate() {
    String date;
    date = txtDate.getText().toString();
    return date;
}

public void addAttractionToItinerary(View v){
    Entities.add(new ItineraryAdapter(ID,NAME,LOCATION,null));
    loadAttractions();
    System.out.println(ItineraryName);
}

public void addTransportToItinerary(View v){
    Entities.add(new ItineraryAdapter(ID,NAME,LOCATION,null));
    loadAttractions();
    System.out.println(ItineraryName);
}

public void loadAttractions(){
    adapter = new myAdapter(Entities);
    ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCreateItinerary);
    ls.setAdapter(adapter);
    for(int i =0; i < finalEntities.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(finalEntities.get(i).NAME + " " + finalEntities.get(i).LOCATION + " " + finalEntities.get(i).TIME);
    }

}

public void onSave(View v){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for(int i = 0; i <finalEntities.size();i++) {
        values.put(DBManager.ColItineraryName,ItineraryName);
        values.put(DBManager.ColDate,txtDate.getText().toString());
        values.put(DBManager.ColName,finalEntities.get(i).NAME );
        values.put(DBManager.ColLocation,finalEntities.get(i).LOCATION);
        values.put(DBManager.ColTime,finalEntities.get(i).TIME);
        long id = db.Insert("Itinerary",values);
        if (id > 0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added to Itinerary", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cannot insert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    saved = true;
}

public void showTimePickerDialog(){
    TextTime = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvCreateItineraryTime);
    TextTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    if(id== DIALOG_ID)
        return new TimePickerDialog(CreateItinerary.this,KTimePickerListner, hour_x, min_x,false);
    return null;
}

protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener KTimePickerListner = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
        hour_x = hourOfDay;
        min_x = minute;
        Toast.makeText(CreateItinerary.this,hour_x+" : " + min_x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setTime(hour_x, min_x);
        TIME = hour_x + ":" + min_x;
        finalEntities.add(new ItineraryAdapter(ID,NAME,LOCATION,TIME));

    }
};

public void setTime(int hour, int min){
    TextTime.setText(hour_x+":"+min_x);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " Selected" ,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    NAME = categoriesList.get(position).getName();
    LOCATION = categoriesList.get(position).getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}

/**
 * Adding spinner data
 * */
private void populateSpinner() {
    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName() + " - " + categoriesList.get(i).getLocation());
        System.out.println(categoriesList.get(i));
    }
    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerAttraction.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinnerTransport.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}

/**
 * Async task to get all attraction categories
 * */
private class GetAttractions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateItinerary.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching attraction categories..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_ATTRACTIONS, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("attraction");

                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                        Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("Id"),
                                catObj.getString("Name"), catObj.getString("Location"));
                        categoriesList.add(cat);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        populateSpinner();
     //   new GetTransport().execute();
    }
}
private class GetTransport extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateItinerary.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching transport categories..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_TRANSPORT, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("transport");

                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                        Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("Id"),
                                catObj.getString("Name"), catObj.getString("Location"));
                        categoriesList.add(cat);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        populateSpinner();
    }

}

class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<ItineraryAdapter> listItem;
    ItineraryAdapter ac;

    public myAdapter(ArrayList<ItineraryAdapter> listItem) {
        this.listItem = listItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ac = listItem.get(position);

        TextView Name = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvCreateItineraryName);
        Name.setText(ac.NAME);

        TextView Location = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvCreateItineraryLocation);
        Location.setText(ac.LOCATION);
        return myView;
    }
    public void deleteItineraryItem(){
        Entities.remove(ID);
        finalEntities.remove(ID);
        loadAttractions();
    }
}
}
```

The public void loadAttractions(){..., is the medthod code that updates the list view, the 2 methods above it relate to separate buttons and add the spinner item to the array list (Entities), thank you to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
```

try this code:

```
 @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listItem.get(position);  //return list item
    }
```